# Maven default profile for separate lifecycle phase

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, spring-test

I have two maven profiles: one for development (active by default) and other one for integration tests

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <properties>
       <maven.profile>dev</maven.profile>
       ...
   </properties>
   <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
</profile>

<profile>
   <id>integration-test</id>
   <properties>
       <maven.profile>integration-test</maven.profile>
       ...
   </properties>
   <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
</profile>
```

To run integration tests, I directly specify profile:

```
mvn failsafe:integration-test -Pintegration
```

Is there some approach, for using *integration-test* profile by default, when run integration tests with failsafe plugin? Or maybe some other elegant approach and best practices how to achieve this with spring test framework, maven and junit to avoid typing every time profile name for integration tests.
Thanks.

Comment: The better approach would probably be not to use profiles in the first place. Why do you need a profile to begin with? What is your use-case?

Comment: I need profiles to have different configuration properties. For example for database, one for development and the other one for integration tests.

Comment: I still don't see the need for a profile. Why not just 2 configuration properties? Maybe you could explain more broadly what it is you want to do.

Comment: I don't want to duplicate properties files. I have for example database properties file, and there properties values are set from pom.xml, so for development environment I use dev profile and dev db connection, but also I have production profile, and when deploy application, I use production profile, and this file with configuration properties is populated with values according to production profile. And the same I want to have for integration tests, the same properties file, but with populated properties from pom.xml for separate profile.

Comment: But, why not explicitely add the `integration-test` to a phase and let it run always? This way you can point to the right configuration file.

Comment: I don't know how to add "integration-test" profile to a "failsafe:integration-test" phase, but other phases run with "dev" that is generally my question

Comment: No, you don't add "integration-test" profile to a "failsafe:integration-test" phase. You declare explicitely the `maven-failsafe-plugin` in your POM and configure it directly.

Comment: sorry, but didn't get you. I configured "failsafe:integration-test" phase to run my integration tests in POM, but, there is no configuration for profile, I can't find such approach in maven documentation, and integration tests are running with default profile "development", while I define other profile in mvn command.